# How could I run a node localhost child process from http request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm experimenting with node and JavaScript trying to create a wireless controller for a motor on raspberry pi. Basically, I made a node localhost and then used a proxy so I can access it over my internet. I made a html page with a slider that currently sends a HTTP request to different paths of the localhost when its on different values which should run a node child process. The problem is that node doesn't see a HTTP request as the same thing as opening the page so it doesn't run the child process. I've tried searching for an alternative but I'm new to all of this and couldn't find anything. Sorry if I explained something wrong or misused a term.
JavaScript code:

```
<script> 
            const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            const urlReverse='https://ip:3000/reverse';
            const urlDrive='https://ip:3000/drive';
            const urlNeutral='https://ip:3000/neutral';
            var rangeslider = document.getElementById("sliderRange"); 
            var output = document.getElementById("demo"); 
                        
            rangeslider.oninput = function() {
                if (this.value < 33){
                    output.innerHTML = 'Reverse';
                    Http.open("POST", urlReverse, true);
                    Http.send();
                }
                else if (this.value >= 33 && this.value <= 66){
                    output.innerHTML = 'Neutral';
                    Http.open("POST", urlNeutral, true);
                    Http.send();

                }
                else if (this.value > 66){
                    output.innerHTML = 'Forward';
                    Http.open("POST", urlDrive, true);
                    Http.send();
                }
            }

        </script>
```

Node code:

```
const http = require('http');
var app = require('express')();

const { exec } = require("child_process");

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('')
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/neutral', function(req, res){
    exec("python3 " + __dirname + "/neutral.py", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
            return;
        }
        if (stderr) {
            console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
            return;
        }
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    });
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/drive', function(req, res){
    exec("python3 " + __dirname + "/drive.py", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
            return;
        }
        if (stderr) {
            console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
            return;
        }
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    });
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/reverse', function(req, res){
    exec("python3 " + __dirname + "/reverse.py", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
            return;
        }
        if (stderr) {
            console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
            return;
        }
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    });
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    
});

// Start the server on port 8080
app.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Node server running on port 8080');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're sending POST requests but only binding routes to GET requests.

Change the `app.get()`s for `drive`/`neutral`/`reverse` to `app.post()` instead.

Comment: Tried this and its not working. When I go on the address it says Cannot GET /.

Comment: Yes, because your browser sends GET requests when you navigate to an address "by hand". Your JavaScript runs `Http.open("POST", ...)` though, sending POST requests.

Comment: I tried again but I cant get it to work. Doesnt say Cannot GET / anymore but still doesnt work.